# Redux-form field array , remove function throwing a weird error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Here is my scenario,

I have an array of objects which i am displaying through redux-form field array, that look something like

```
  [{
    index: 0,
    overlapRecord: '127.0.0.1'
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    overlapRecord: '127.0.0.1'
  }],
```

my code goes something like

```
<div className = "delete" onClick = {()=>field.remove(index)}> DeleteButton </div>
```

When i am trying to perform an On Click, I get the following error:

```
"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 2 in" at deleteInWithPath.
```

Any Ideas on what would be the reason for the error can be highly 
  appreciated.

Stack Trace:
[image]

Comment: StackTrace would be useful. Can you show us in which line the error is occuring?

Comment: @AmitJoki It looks like the redux-form field Array internal code is complaining.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could reproduce this in a JSFiddle kind of environment with a minimal setup?

Comment: @AmitJoki I  am not sure, If i will be able to do that..It's not my system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the on click event a callback
Like

```
onclick={
 ()=>{
      field.remove(index)
     }
}
```

Comment: arrow function syntax does not require curly braces in case only one statement in body

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late for this answer, but if someone else happens to have the same problem:

We had the same problem in our codebase, after a day or two looking for solutions we found that the problem was inside our validators.

We were returning:

```
const errors = {
  arrayFieldName: ''
};
```

And when changing it to:

```
const errors = {
  arrayFieldName: []
};
```

It worked correctly.

You can see in their [Redux Form FieldArray Example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/fieldarrays/), that they're returning an empty array in case there are no errors and there is information in the array, or an `{ _error: 'message' }` if there is no data present.